# Push the button and change randomly the image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in this site, but I follow it for many years.

In this test I'm trying to change the image pressing the button. The image will be generate randomly. In short, I have 2 dice and 1 button to change them.
Here, the code.

HTML:

```
<tr align="center">
<td width="20%"> 
<input type="button" name="tira" value="Tira" onClick="lancio()"> 
<td><img id="scelta1" alt="alt1" width="30px"></img> 
<td id="scelta2">
<img src="images/dado2.gif" alt="2" width="30px"></img>
```

Here my javascript.

```
<script>
var scelta1;
var temp=0;

var image = new Array(6);
image[0]= 'images/dado1.gif';
image[1]= 'images/dado2.gif';
image[2]= 'images/dado3.gif';
image[3]= 'images/dado4.gif';
image[4]= 'images/dado5.gif';
image[5]= 'images/dado6.gif';

function lancio(){
    temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6));

        if(temp == 0){
            document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[0];
            document.getElementById("alt1").value = temp;
            return scelta1;
        }
        else if(temp == 1){
            document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[1];
            document.getElementById("alt1").value = temp;
            return scelta1;
        }
        else if(temp == 2){
            document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[2];
            document.getElementById("alt1").value = temp;
            return scelta1;
        }
        else if(temp == 3){
            document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[3];
            document.getElementById("alt1").value = temp;
            return scelta1;
        }
        else if(temp == 4){
            document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[4];
            document.getElementById("alt1").value = temp;
            return scelta1;
        }
        else if(temp == 5){
            document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[5];
            document.getElementById("alt1").value = temp;
            return scelta1;
        }

    }
}

</script>
```

Thank you for support and I hope in many answers. Sorry if I wrong something with forum's rules.

Bye

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What's the problem?

Comment: There is no </img>-tag, you should delete it.

Comment: You should close your <td> before opening another table data cell (missing </td>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nikola: Thanks for tag  I didn't know. Syntax maybe is good, but when i try to click on button the image doesn't change.

```
<!--DOCTYPE HTML W3C-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prova</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lanciodadi.js">
        </script>
        <link href="stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body link="#7FFFD4">
        <div style="color: white"><a href="javascript: void{0}">Login</a> <span>/</span><a href="javascript: void{0}">Registrati</a></div>
        <p align="center"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="logo" width="30%"></p>
        <table>
            <th colspan="3" style="color: red"><b>Statistiche PARTITA 1</b>
            <tr><td width="20%"> Nome <td><input type="text" name="g1" value="Giocatore 1" style="text-align: center" width="40%"><td><input type="text" name="g2" value="Giocatore 2" style="text-align: center" width="40%">
            <tr><td width="20%"> Soldi <td><input type="text" name="soldi1" value="1000" style="text-align: center" width="40%"><td><input type="text" name="soldi2" value="1000" style="text-align: center" width="40%">
            <tr><td width="20%"> Info <td><textarea rows="3"></textarea><td><textarea rows="3"></textarea>
            <!-- QUA I DADI DEVONO CAMBIARE -->
            <tr align="center"><td width="20%"> <input type="button" name="tira" value="Tira" onClick="lancio();"> <td><img src="images/dado1.gif" id="scelta1" alt="alt1" width="30px"> <td id="scelta2"><img src="images/dado2.gif" alt="2" width="30px">
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

lanciodadi.js

```
function lancio(){  
        var temp=0;
        var image = new Array(6);
        image[0]= 'images/dado1.gif';
        image[1]= 'images/dado2.gif';
        image[2]= 'images/dado3.gif';
        image[3]= 'images/dado4.gif';
        image[4]= 'images/dado5.gif';
        image[5]= 'images/dado6.gif';

        temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6));

        document.getElementById("scelta1").src = image[temp];


    }
}
```

@Sven: Thanks! This is a nice method! It works, I'll use it. Thanks everybody :-)

Answer (score 0):

First there is no such thing as `<img></img>`. It is a self closing tag.

```
<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" />
<button onclick=lancio();>yoo</button>
```

Here's the code that will work for you:

```
<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" id="image" />



function lancio() {

  var temp=0;

  var image = new Array(6);
image[0]= 'http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg';
image[1]= 'http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg';
image[2]= 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg';
image[3]= 'http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg';
image[4]= 'http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg';
image[5]= 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg';

  temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

  document.getElementById("image").src=image[temp];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using the array and the ifs. You could choose a rather simpler way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //global variables for later number access
            var diceValue1 = 0;
            var diceValue2 = 0;

            function calculateDice(index)
            {
                //get the image with the specified index
                var image = document.getElementById("dice" + index);
                //calculate a number from 1 to 6
                var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)) + 1;

                window["diceValue" + index] = number; //assign global vars
                image.src = "images/dado" + number + ".gif"; //assign image
                image.alt = number.toString(); //assign alt
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="dice1" src="blank.gif" alt=""/>
        <img id="dice2" src="blank.gif" alt=""/>
        <input type="button" value="Roll the dice" onclick="calculateDice(1); calculateDice(2);"/>
    </body>
</html>
```